# How can I prove that LTL formula is valid?

Tags: logic, model-checking, linear-temporal-logic, logical-validity

I do not know with which technique i can prove if a LTL forumula is valid.

Let's say we have for example this one: ¬q U(¬p ∧ ¬q) → ¬Gp. How can prove if this valid or not? (should be true in any state of any model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main technique in order to prove validity (or more in general, to solve the problem of satisfiability over a definite model) for a LTL formula.

The first one is based on semantic tableau, analogous to the case of modal logic, [here](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Eangelo.montanari/LTL-SAT.pdf) you can find some explanations.

The other one is based on automata, in particular it is possible to translate a formula in a Buchi automaton, and then one can check satisfiability paths on the automaton. In the case of the validity, you have to translate the **negation** of your formula and verify that the automaton you get is the empty one. This can be performed algorithmically, [this](http://www.lsv.fr/%7Egastin/ltl2ba/index.php) is a useful tool (by the way, you formula is actually valid, try inserting this string: NOT(((NOT q)U(NOT p && NOT q))->NOT G(p))), at the same page you can find reference about the implementation of the translation algorithm.

Comment: wow thank you. This helps me a lot. Very usefull tool!!